# check user role when wordpress user role are login?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, authentication, custom-wordpress-pages

wordpress check which user role are login and some fields are not showing how it's possible.

=> i need  to the , when editor role user login, then appointkart plugin location menu not showing, And administrator role login the location menu are show.

[image: check this image:]
Check this image:

Comment: you can just find a code and customise it as per need.

Comment: Thanks for comment @VasimVanzara
it's done i have check in header.php file and put role condition

Comment: In which header.php file??

Comment: is this your custom plugin??

Comment: @VasimVanzara  plugin header.php file
No this not custom plugin but customise this plugin

Comment: please do css is better one.attache a class conditionally

Comment: Ok thank you @VasimVanzara  it's Done